# Unexpected behavior using both: unique and == function

Tags: r, data.table

I guess there is a bug in the unique-function of the data.table (1.9.6) package:

Small example:

```
test <- data.table(a = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "4"), 
                   b = letters[1:8], 
                   d = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))

   a b     d
1: 1 a  TRUE
2: 1 b  TRUE
3: 2 c FALSE
4: 2 d FALSE
5: 3 e  TRUE
6: 4 f FALSE
7: 4 g FALSE
8: 4 h FALSE

test[d == TRUE, `:=` (b = "M")]
test <- unique(test, by = c("a", "b"))

   a b     d
1: 1 M  TRUE
2: 2 c FALSE
3: 2 d FALSE
4: 3 M  TRUE
5: 4 f FALSE
6: 4 g FALSE
7: 4 h FALSE
```

At this point everything is perfect but now I want to select only rows where column d is true:

```
test[d == TRUE]
   a b    d
1: 1 M TRUE
```

But the result is wrong.

Comment: FWIW, `test[(d == TRUE)]`, `test[d == 1]` and `test[(d)]`  give all the right result.

Comment: Strange... this instead works: `test[test$d==TRUE]`

Comment: This indeed looks like a bug that probably been caused by the secondary index. Maybe somehow related to [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1704). Either-way, SO is not meant for bug reports. Bugs should be reported on GH. Also, using `==` on a logical vector doesn't make sense to me. Why not just `test[(d)]`?

Comment: After removing the keys with `setkey(test, NULL)`, `test[d==TRUE]` works as espected.

Comment: using `test[!duplicated(test, by = c("a", "b"))]` instead of unique works

Comment: @nicola can you please explain what's the differencs between `test[d]` and `test[(d)]`

Comment: @fc9.30 The latter ensures that `d` is evaluated instead of using a secondary key which is known to have some bugs in the CRAN version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That bug was just fixed in development repository.

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(a = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "4"), 
                   b = letters[1:8], 
                   d = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
test[d == TRUE, `:=` (b = "M")]
test <- unique(test, by = c("a", "b"))
test[d == TRUE]
#   a b    d
#1: 1 M TRUE
#2: 3 M TRUE
```

Development version data.table was already published in drat repo and can be [easily installed](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) by:

```
install.packages("data.table", repos="https://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table", type="source")
```

Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 0):

Without solving the bug, it does work with normal data.frame syntax:

```
test[test$d, ]
```

or

```
test[test$d == TRUE, ]
```